# Prevent LongListSelector to change position when adding items

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, observablecollection, longlistselector

I have implemented custom LongListSelector control which send event when user hits the top of the list. When the event is raised, I load more data from web api and add the items to beginning of the collection like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> _items;
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
{
    get { return _items; }
    set
    {
        _items = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Items);
    }
}

...

foreach (Item newItem in newItemsToAdd)
{
   this.Items.Insert(0, newItem);
}
```

This leads to case when user has scrolled to top of the list and I add more items to the collection(list), LongListSelector updates its position to top of new items.

How can I prevent LongListSelector to change its scroll position when I add items to beginning of the collection?